# Pasar proyecto Java a exe

Tags: java

necesito saber si es posible pasar un proyecto Java a un .exe, el IDE que utilizo es Intel J Idea. Tengo ahora mismo dos archivos .java: el Main y una clase llamada 'student' que he creado.
Gracias.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697324/executable-jar-and-double-click/23192650#23192650

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El compilador de Java no puede generar un ejecutable `.exe` nativo de Windows.

Sin embargo, existen varias alternativas que puedes usar para lograr generar un ejecutable `.exe` a partir de un ejecutable `.jar`.  La mayoría son envolturas nativas (wrappers) de aplicaciones java.

- **[Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)**. Es una herramienta multiplataforma para envolver aplicaciones Java distribuidas `.jar` en ejecutables nativos ligeros de Windows. Muy popular. 
  Recomiendo este práctico [tutorial](http://masdejava.blogspot.com/2016/04/convertir-jar-ejecutable-exe-con.html#.W3Tasbjm-Co).
- **[Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/)**.
  Es una herramienta avanzada de creación de instaladores de Windows para instalar, actualizar y configurar programas de forma segura y confiable.
  Recomiendo este [tutorial](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java.html), está en inglés pero es fácil de entender.
- **[Excelsior JET](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)**. Permite implemente aplicaciones Java como ejecutables nativos optimizados en múltiples plataformas.
- **[Jar2Exe](http://www.jar2exe.com/)**. Jar2Exe es un convertidor archivos jar a archivos binarios ejecutivos para Windows, Mac y Linux.
- **[JSmoother](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/).**
  Genera un ejecutable .exe que actúa como un envoltorio (wrapper) para una ejecutable .jar. Es algo viejo, no se ha actualizado desde hace mucho.

Comment: Una respuesta muy útil, muchísimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el Lauch4j, el cual es un programa que te ayuda a generar los .
exe
de los jar.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/launch4j-3/3.12/

Solo debes de descargarlo, luego puedes genera el .exe de jar que tengas, es muy fácil e intuitivo

Comment: No comprendo el voto negativo a esta respuesta. Si bien es verdad que la respuesta se puede elaborar un poco más, la respuesta es correcta y se entiende perfectamente.